# SQL Self join with mapping table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables defined below.  One is a table for our groups, one is a table that maps a group as a subgroup of another.

```
table customers_groups:
    id              int auto_increment primary key
    group_shortname varchar(16)           not null

table subgroup_mappings:
    group_id    int not null,
    subgroup_id int not null,
    constraint group_id unique (group_id, subgroup_id),
    constraint customers_subgroups_table_ibfk_1 foreign key (group_id) references customers_groups (id),
    constraint customers_subgroups_table_ibfk_2 foreign key (subgroup_id) references customers_groups (id)
```

I wanted to be able to join the `customers_groups` table to itself, along with the `subgroup_mappings` table so that the resulting table contained both the parent group, and the child group.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: There would be no self join. You simply have to join customers_groups table 2 times to subgroup_mappings, once on group_id and once on subgroup_id to get their descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   cg.id as group_id,
   cg.group_shortname as group_shortname, 
   cs.id as subgroup_id,
   cs.group_shortname as subgroup_shortname 
from subgroup_mappings s
   inner join customers_groups cg on s.group_id = cg.id
   inner join customers_groups cs on s.group_id = cs.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one table

Of course there are lots more possibilities, to get the vwanted information.

```
CREATE TABLE  customers_groups(
    id              int auto_increment primary key,
    group_shortname varchar(16)           not null,
  parent_id int,
  constraint customers_subgroups_table_ibfk_1 foreign key (parent_id) references customers_groups (id))
```

```
INSERT INTO customers_groups (group_shortname,parent_id) VALUES ('A', NULL)
```

```
INSERT INTO customers_groups (group_shortname,parent_id) VALUES ('B', 1),('C', 1),('D', 1)
```

```
INSERT INTO customers_groups (group_shortname,parent_id) VALUES ('E', 2),('F', 3),('G', 5)
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, group_shortname) AS
(
  SELECT id,group_shortname  FROM customers_groups WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, CONCAT(cte.group_shortname,'->', c.group_shortname)  
  FROM cte  JOIN customers_groups c ON cte.id = c.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

| id | group_shortname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A->B |
| 3 | A->C |
| 4 | A->D |
| 5 | A->B->E |
| 6 | A->C->F |
| 7 | A->B->E->G |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zza_mU75)